# Override variable in yaml

Tags: yaml

I have a yml config file that looks like this:

```
default: &default
  aws_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  aws_secret_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'] %>
  region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
  aws_s3_bucket: <%= ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'] %>
  aws_s3_host: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"

development:
  <<: *default
```

I want in `development` to extend with all the default values, but override the bucket name. How can I achieve that? Probably that is a very basic question, but I couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use python, that's very simple:

```
import yaml

# read your first file
with open("basefile.yaml", 'r') as f:
    conf = yaml.load(f)

# read your second file
with open("devfile.yaml", 'r') as f:
    devconf = yaml.load(f)

# update the first dictionnary with the values of the second
conf.update(devconf)

# write it in a new file
with open("result.yaml", 'w+') as f:
    yaml.dump(conf, f)
```